# AudioOutputUnitStart() fails with error 268451843

Tags: ios, audiounit

I had the call to `AudioOutputUnitStart()` fail once with error code `268451843`.
The only information I was able to find is from [ossstatus.com](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=268451843), error description is

> Didn't get a message within the timeout value.

There were no errors during AudioUnit initialisation and the error has happened once. I don't know how to proceed to debug it. Have you ever encountered similar problems?

AudioUnit is initialised and started by the CallKit thread on audio session activation.

The problem has occurred after removing and inserting back the headphones.